# Rep points for questions

Tags: discussion, reputation, challenges

Right now we're using the standard +5/-2 for questions and +10/-2 for answers. However, this site is different from the trilogy and most other SE sites: coming up with a question generally takes more effort. I believe the value of questions:answers here is higher than on other sites.

How about we raise the rep gained from up-votes on questions to +10?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Not only does it take more effort to pose a good problem here than asking questions on most other sites (not to mention how hard it will become to come up with good ideas once a lot of problems have already been posed), it's also much more selfless to ask a question:

On most other sites the primary reason to ask a question is because you want to know the answer. So the primary benefit you get for asking the question is finding out the answer. Here the main benefit of posing a problem is that the users have another problem to try their luck at. So basically the answerers are the ones who most benefit from a question.

Further meta.stackoverflow also gives you 10 reputation points for question upvotes for similar reasons, so we wouldn't be the only exception to the rule.

So in short: Yes, I'm completely in favour of your proposal.

Comment: +1 Very nice. I was iffy about the idea at first, but now that you mentioned this, I can understand better why it's a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be a moot point, at least for the time being. [Asked on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242718/212780), the response is that it would change the core functionality too much. This may change down the road, but it seems unlikely to me.

Answer (score -1):

On the whole I think this makes sense, but...

...the curmudgeon in me notes that so far we've not been getting the best possible questions. Not so much in terms of the puzzles posed (though we could use some work there too (yeah, I know, if I'm complaining I should do something about it, and I'm still thinking)), but in terms of careful specification and description.

Comment: I kind of get the feeling this is a reason for bumping up the question rep. More chance of reward will result in more careful attention to detail.

Comment: The obvious answer to that is of course that questions with lacklustre specifications should not be upvoted until the OP clarifies the specification in response to your comments. And the more an upvote is worth, the more motivated askers would be to respond to such requests in hopes of upvotes. Put another way: greater reward for good questions encourages more effort to produce good questions.

Answer (score -1):

I'm in favor of that!

How about also raising reputation based on the number of valid (e.g. up-voted) answers submitted for the question?

Comment: If you get many answers, but no upvotes, there is something wrong with your question, I guess. Maybe all questions get to few upvotes, but that would be a reason to educate all the users.

Comment: My point is that questions ought to be compelling enough (at least on Code Golf) that other users wish to respond and upvote answers.  Unlike other SOs, there isn't much interest in Code Golf so it would behoove us to provide artificial incentives until we've hit some critical mass and are producing questions on a regular basis.