# Close reason needs to be reworded

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

Read this meta post:

> [Let's decide what kind of non-challenge questions we want once and for all](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1723/18487)

Then read this close reason:

> Questions without an **objective primary winning criterion** are off-topic, as they make it impossible to indisputably decide which entry should win.

Do you see the conflict? We allow non-challenge questions, but our close reason says that they are off topic. We need to reword our close reason. I propose a one word change:

> Challenges without an **objective primary winning criterion** are off-topic, as they make it impossible to indisputably decide which entry should win.

All I did was change the word "Questions" to "Challenges." Problem solved. Thoughts?

Comment: I think it's pretty clear already that the close reason doesn't apply to questions that aren't challenges (it wouldn't even make sense in that context anyway), so a trivial one-word change wouldn't really do much.

Comment: Clear to whom? You, me, and anyone else who happens to have seen the meta post? I saw you link to it in the chat earlier today, which tells me that not everyone knows about it. And honestly, why *not* make a one word change if it adds even a little bit of clarity?

Comment: I support this change.  Out of context (such as new users casually browsing the site and seeing a closed question for the first time), the current statement is actually *incorrect*.

Comment: I support this change. It clarifies that this applies only to challenges, which is an important distinction to make since we allow non-challenge questions and that has caused confusion in the past. I am marking this as [meta-tag:status-review] and hopefully we can get this changed.

Comment: There have been some major changes to the close reason UI since this request was created - as such, I'd love it if y'all would take a look at [this guide on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362581/should-we-update-clarify-our-help-center-with-respect-to-other-sites-and-teams/362584#362584) and revamp the close reason more completely to take advantage of the new fields. Once that's done, re-tag this as status-review and I'll edit it for y'all :) cc @hyper-neutrino