# The tips tag is currently golf focused. Can this be made explicit one way or the other?

Tags: discussion, tag-wikis

The [tag wiki](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/tips/info) for [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) mentions

> either golfing or programming challenges

but then the rest of the wording and examples cover only aspects related to golf or golfing languages.

There doesn't currently seem to be a consistent consensus on meta to point to when someone posts a tips question that isn't about golf. Ideally, the tips tag wiki would explicitly mention fastest code, algorithms, and anything else that may cause disagreement, and state whether each is included in the tips tag (and therefore on topic).

A couple of years ago we had a meta post to settle [what kind of non-challenge questions we want once and for all](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1723/lets-decide-what-kind-of-non-challenge-questions-we-want-once-and-for-all), but the voting on the answers seems to give two contradictory messages.

- [Questions about improving code golf / code challenge skills](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1724/20283) **+23** [+33/-10]
- [Questions about improving algorithms](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1728/20283) **-5** [+7/-12]

The first seems to include fastest code / algorithm improvements, but the body mentions only golf. It's hard to judge whether the upvotes support algorithm improvements or just golf. The second is specifically about algorithms and has downvotes, but also a significant number of upvotes.

Can we make the tips tag wiki definitive?

Comment: Somewhat [related](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/8664/31625).

Comment: [Related.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5221/8478)

Comment: [Related](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5804/tips-for-providing-high-quality-answers-in-popularity-contests)