# Hey Stack Exchange, how are we doing?

Tags: support, beta-status, site-health

The last time we heard from a Stack Exchange community manager was in [March of 2014](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192/20469), when [Grace Note](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/146126) came to talk to us about the progress we've made as a site. That was back when [code-trolling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-trolling) was a thing, and the community's response to the news wasn't particularly positive given how code trolling had affected the site's overall quality.

Now here we are, almost 2 years after Grace Note gave us that update. [code-trolling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-trolling) is off topic, dead, and buried. Our site stats, regardless of how much they *actually* matter, are excellent (as FlagAsSpam so nicely laid out for us [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271974/287795)), save for the average number of questions we get per day. Our rate falls short of the expected 10, but sites have graduated with less.

Whether or not we expect or even want to graduate, it would be nice to have some feedback from the folks at Stack Exchange on our progress and their take on us as part of the greater SE ecosystem.

So hey, SE, how are we doing? Notice us, senpai.

---

**Update:** Here we are, over a month later, and we've been averaging over 10 questions per day for a while now! As of this writing, we're at [10.8 Q/day](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4570/code-golf-programming-puzzles).

Comment: Thankyou for posting this. I have been wondering the same thing. +1, and eagerly awaiting an answer.

Comment: Wow, you read my mind! I was wondering the same thing too. But... how will we get Stack Exchange to notice our request, though? Grace Note last came here 3 months ago!

Comment: @Hipe99 The community managers at Stack Exchange peruse the various site metas. Grace Note or another community manager should see this... eventually.

Comment: @AlexA. They'll see it soon™

Comment: @AlexA. Would it be inappropriate to post this to the main meta?

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Yep. This is definitely a question for our meta since it's specific to this site.

Comment: ... crickets ... tumbleweed ...

Comment: Maybe we should poke it...?

Comment: `Admin is typing...`

Comment: [7.9 questions a day](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4570/code-golf-programming-puzzles) means you all are [getting close](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614/1438). I'm guessing (at this rate) you'll get an election later in the year and [a design sometime later](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263905/1438). Not much else to say, really.

Comment: @JonEricson I'm an outsider to PPCG, so I don't have a substantial investment, but it seems to me that the 10 Q/d threshold that's set for the more SE-traditional Q&A sites is inappropriately high for PPCG. I'm most active to date on Chem.SE; people go there because they *don't* know things, and there are a lot of things that a lot of people don't know. *Here*, though, people only post "questions" when they've actively thought up something (hopefully) clever. 10 coding challenges per day is a much higher bar than 10 questions per day. Graduate them, already!

Comment: @JonEricson Hey, guess what! We're above 10 Q/day and holding steady! :D

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So I guess senpai noticed us. See below for a special note from Grace Note.

## [Congratulations, you're graduating!](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8538/20469)

Comment: I'll accept my own answer because ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯