# Congratulations, you're graduating!

Tags: discussion, graduation, announcement

It's a big day, and I know you folks have been waiting a reeeaaal long while. Double waiting, you might even say, since unfortunately we made you wait even longer after initial news. But, let's make it official! You've been cleared for graduation by the Stack Exchange Community Team! Programming Puzzles & Code Golf met our threshold for [graduation-worthy sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites) and after a review, the Community Team determined that you're good to go. Reaching 'mature community' status is a big milestone, and you should be very proud.

Your site actually passed this threshold several weeks ago. We're... still kinda looking into why that happened, but your good news shouldn't have to wait!

What does this mean exactly? Graduation works in two phases. Starting today, you'll receive the following benefits:

- You will soon have an election for community-voted moderators - there is still some backlog in hosting elections so it'll most likely be during next month that yours will begin.
- You will no longer see the "beta" label attached to your site's name.
- You will become eligible for question migration paths with the rest of the network.
- You will soon be able to select your own community ads. Give me a moment to set these up later this week.

The site will still receive a full design from one of our designers, which will be packaged with an increase in the amount of reputation needed to access each privilege. It's no secret that our backlog for site designs is long, so instead of making you wait to receive all the parts of graduation at once, we wanted to [give you the things we could give](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260754/feedback-requested-design-independent-graduation) you now. We think we've hammered out most of the bugs in the process,, but there are still likely to be some left -  so if you come across anything out of place, please report it on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) using the [graduating-sites] tag.

This site has reached this point because of your generous contributions. Together, you've created a valuable resource that helps people. Congratulations on all you've accomplished.

---

As an added note, [we're aware of some discussion about certain elements which need to be worked on](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8350/were-not-a-qa-site-but-what-should-be-done-about-it), especially surrounding verbiage on the site being a "Q&A" site. Different parts of that are still under review, but wanted to drop off word that we are indeed looking into it.

Comment: Wooooooooooooo!

Comment: \o/ \o/ \o/ \o/ \o/

Comment: I don't even know what I'm going to do with my life anymore.

Comment: Own community ads, woo!;D

Comment: `ಠ_ಠ,` A single tear is shed as we finally learn of our graduation after 5 years of waiting.

Comment: "Together, you've created a valuable resource that helps people." Oh the irony. :) (More seriously, this is amazing news. We've been working towards this for a long time, so I second everything Alex said in his answer.)

Comment: Man, now I have to find another beta site to make [tag:forever-beta] jokes about...

Comment: "valuable resource that helps people", help how exactly? Write bad code? :)

Comment: Nah, it keeps their brain stimulated thinking of wicked ways to abuse languages :P

Comment: @SimonForsberg ಠ_ಠ

Comment: I want the *beta* back as part of the new design.

Comment: Python, 12 bytes: `voteCount+=1`

Comment: Is this an early april fools joke?

Comment: The official graduation date is set for [November 1st](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5834/34718).

Comment: :') [my response to graduation](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EMzFI.gif)

Comment: Aw yus thank the overlords for this wondrous miracle. Can I get a hallelujah!

Comment: @DJMcGoathem You can say that's a polyglot. Off the top of my head this works in: python, java, groovy, scala, javascript, ...

Comment: I've spent a huge amount of time lurking on this site, and while I'm not a particularly active part of the community, it's a fantastic achievement. Congratulations to everybody!

Comment: Is it bad that I had to check that this post wasn't by @Geobits before believing it?

Comment: Super exciting! I know the theme may take a while to come around, but glad to see that we've finally made it, and looking forward to the quality changes it brings =)

Comment: YEAH! GJ everyone!

Comment: @muddyfish Bad? No... it shows you have good sense ;)

Comment: Does this mean I'm going to lose trusted user privilege? D:

Comment: @JoeZ Only after the privilege changes but that isn't yet.

Comment: Is the community ads thing available yet? You said it would be available within the week but it's been nearly two weeks.

Comment: Yay!!! After 5 years we finally graduated!

Answer (score 90):

Needless to say this is fantastic news. I'd just like to take a moment to say

## THANK YOU

both to the Stack Exchange Community Team as well as to our wonderful community. Together we've built something amazing and I'm exceptionally proud to be a part of it. This is a day that we've [often joked](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5834/20469) would never come, but with our dedication we've made it a reality. If you're reading this, you helped us reach this milestone—perhaps the ultimate milestone a Stack Exchange site can hope to achieve—so you should be proud as well!

PPCG is honestly one of the most creative, passionate groups of people I've ever come across. I'm honored to have been able to serve as a pro-tem moderator and I'm looking forward to continuing to be a part of this community as we move into this next phase of our existence.

Comment: Side note: Sometimes I wish h1 was bigger and more obtrusive.

Comment: you've totally misunderstood this site. Things around here should be short and small.

Comment: @SimonForsberg It's [font-bowling].

Comment: Should have been: "English, 2 bytes - `ty`".

Comment: Maybe we can delay it to (month) the 1st? :P

Comment: Bigger is `<font size="100">THANK YOU!!!</font>`, 36 bytes.

Comment: @RikerW Doesn't work for me

Comment: @mınxomaτ Is there a reason you didn't post that as an answer? ;)

Comment: @mınxomaτ Or "Wingdings, 1 byte - ☺" (Alt-074)

Answer (score 28):

Yay! I'm so happy, and glad to hear this awesome news! However, it brings up a question. Are there any plans to change the number of [reputation for challenges?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7683/increase-reputation-awarded-for-questions) When this was requested 2 months ago, there was overwhelmingly positive support for making this happen, but no response from anyone who actually had the ability to do something about it. Is this still something that is adjustable on a per-site basis? I imagine this is a "Wait until full graduation, and we'll talk it over then" but we'd all love a quick update on it now.

Comment: [Grace Note responded in chat recently](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=27434068#27434068)