# (When) do my mod tools go away?

Tags: support, reputation, site-design, moderation, graduation

I opened SE a few minutes ago and was pleasantly surprised to see I'd reached 2k rep, and alongside that gained access to mod tools (*sehr interessant*). I was mostly very confused, since I was certain mod tools come at 10k rep.

By browsing `http://SITENAME.stackexchange.com/help/privileges` on various sites, it seems like **recently graduated sites without designs** put mod tools at 2k, where graduated sites **with designs** put mod tools at 10k. (compare: [Aviation.se](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) and [ELL.se](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).)

Searching about this on Mother Meta and PPCG Meta have not turned up anything (because I have no idea what this phenomenon is actually called), so I'll ask here:

1. Does the rep-requirement-shift come when we get a design (or is it a coincidence?), and
2. if I still have 2,004 rep at that time, will my mod tools go away?

Comment: `s/mod.*tools/privileges/g` and this could be a more generally-helpful question, I guess

Comment: Congrats on 2k rep, by the way. :)

Comment: @AlexA. Thanks :D

Comment: It'll be awesome to get a new site design, but it'll really suck to lose privileges. I only *just* got my "trusted user" privilege, and I'll be really sad to lose it. =(

Comment: @DrGreenEggsandHamDJ I know what you mean; if I wasn't a moderator I would also lose trusted user privileges since I'm under 20k reputation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the privilege thresholds increase when sites get custom designs. See [Congratulations, you're graduating!](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8538/20469). So if you still have about 2000 reputation when we get a design, you'll still have your edits applied immediately, but access to all privileges above that will be removed. See [Stack Overflow's privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) for comparison.