# When is Programming Puzzles & Code Golf getting community ads?

Tags: support, status-completed, graduation, advertising

Over 3 months ago, on February 23, 2016, it was announced that this SE site [was graduating](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8538/congratulations-youre-graduating).

That post said that

> You will soon be able to select your own community ads. Give me a moment to set these up later this week.

The ads were not set up that week and still haven't been.

Last week our mod Alex updated us with the [chat message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30174007#30174007)

> Graduation perks update: Community ads were inadvertently overlooked and the CMs will get on that soon. Our site-specific text is under review and we'll get a design once we get updated text.

So presumably our community ads are just around the corner, but given that we've waited 3 months longer that we were originally supposed to, and that our graduation process has had other delays and snafus, I'd like to make sure.

When is Programming Puzzles & Code Golf getting community ads?

**June 20th Update:** It's being [looked into](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5019879#5019879).

Comment: Senpai, notice us!

Comment: This is getting ridiculous...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry about the delay here. [The new thread is now up](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9463/community-promotion-ads-2016), and will shortly afterwards be hooked up to start displaying ads.