# Community Promotion Ads - 2016

Tags: discussion, community-ads

You've graduated... a while ago. This is quite overdue, but let us not wait any longer. We present to you, Community Promotion Ads!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- code puzzle blogs and websites
- interesting challenge sites
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **300 x 250 pixels**, or **600 x 500 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of **150 KB**
- **If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if the image is 600 x 500) surrounding it.**

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/9463).

Comment: What does "*or double that if high DPI*" mean? Am I correct to assume that it has nothing to do with the image metadata and is solely mentioned to provide a link between the size constraint and the border constraint?

Comment: If you have an image that is 600x500 instead of 300x250, the border should be 2px instead so that when it's cut down to 300x250, the border is undistortedly 1px.

Comment: Putting the _title_ in the _alt text_? This isn't [_internetexplorer.stackexchange.com_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Defining_Cross-Browser_Tooltips) or something! More seriously though, why not use the markdown for alt text to specify the alt text and the markdown for title text for title text? (`![alt](http://example.com "Title text")`) This has the added benefit that it's actually possible to view what title text we're voting for (in an easy way).

Answer (score 57):

[image: Have a challenge idea? Just like sand? Join us in the Sandbox!]

Comment: I thought we should have at least _one_ community ad for the sandbox. I'm open to tweaks in grammar and wording as I'm not very perfect at all that.

Comment: The "Just like sand?" line confused me at first, as I thought it was referring to the earlier line and suggesting that your challenge was like sand. I'm not sure if that was just me, but maybe adding "Do you" and "Or do you" to the beginning of each line would be better? That said I totally agree with having an ad go to the sandbox.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman [I did the latter](http://i.stack.imgur.com/L15TI.png) [but geobits suggested against](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27848633#27848633) so I'll do the former. update: done

Comment: I only objected to the lack of capitalization, not the wording.

Comment: I support the change of "Just like sand?" to "Just love sand?"

Comment: IMO `Not all challenges are well-received in the first try, but there's a place to improve.` is better than `Have a challenge idea? Just like sand?`.

Comment: Note that this currently might break the "If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it." rule. The bg is not white but pretty close.

Comment: This one is cute but I'm concerned that it doesn't indicate it's an ad for PPCG (or even SE) anywhere. Maybe a PPCG logo/text near the bottom somewhere?

Comment: I propose that the first two lines be `Programming challenge idea?/Love sand?`.

Comment: @HelkaHomba community ads aren't ads _for PPCG_ per se, but just things to advertise _at PPCG_, so I don't think I need to do that. Looking at other sites' community ads that also doesn't seem necessary to specify the site.

Comment: Ads *for* PPCG, to be displayed on other SE sites, are [here](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/8389/lets-make-more-ads-for-our-site-2016-edition)

Comment: @dorukayhan I'll try to golf that first :P

Comment: @Downgoat XD So what about `Some first challenges get downvoted, but there's a place to improve.`?

Comment: "*Have a challenge idea? Iron out the bugs before posting. Join us in the Sandbox*". I personally **hate** sand, but that's completely irrelevant to sandboxing.

Comment: is that sandbox clipart free to use?

Comment: @PeterTaylor that sounds good. I'm not on my computer right now though so I'll change it in a bit

Comment: lol `Do you just love sand?`

Comment: @PeterTaylor Do you hate sand because it's coarse and rough and irritating and gets everywhere?

Comment: I agree with @Peter's comment. Otherwise this isn't very descriptive.

Comment: @Downgoat: Friendly reminder to change the text. I do like Peter's suggestion as well.

Comment: @El'endiaStarman >_> I saved the png but forgot to update the ad. Done now

Comment: @Downgoat: Fantastic.

Comment: @Downgoat I liked the other version better. Can we have both? That way, sometimes one would show, then sometimes the other. :D

Answer (score 55):

[image: Over 170 online interpreters. Free of charge, open source, and ad-free.]

Answer (score 31):

[image: Know how to vote!]

Comment: In light of [this](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/10127/32352) discussion. Feel free to point out if it's **a.** a terrible idea or **b.** a terrible design.

Comment: Not sure about the idea, but it's too visually busy for me. The focus of the ad is unclear at first glance. Make "know how to vote" the main focus that your eyes jump to, relative to the remaining content.

Comment: How about just a big ol' downvote button? ;)

Comment: @Geobits Very tempting... In all seriousness though, I think that more upvotes for interesting solutions is better than downvotes for less-then-interesting solutions (since usually they're not *bad* per se).

Comment: I don't think people should downvote trivial answers to trivial questions (although I do approve of downvoting trivial questions, which may be how I have even more downvotes than Geobits) or boring ports. Abstaining from upvotes would be sufficient.

Comment: I'm personally not on board with downvoting trivial challenges as long as they're as well specified as more complicated ones. Simple challenges are great fun for esoteric programming language which are often too hard to use to solve harder problems with. Likewise, I don't think answers without explanation should be downvoted - they just shouldn't be upvoted. We want people to be able to golf here and post their answers even if they don't have the time to add an explanation. This shouldn't be punished (it's just that nice explanation should be encouraged).

Comment: Generally I think that calling for downvotes on specific things that aren't completely obvious (invalid answers, loophole abuse) could have some unwanted side-effects.

Comment: @MartinEnder http://i.stack.imgur.com/9XsvS.png would be an alternative approach. But please say if you feel that community ads would not be appropriate for this goal, either way.

Comment: @sanchises I definitely prefer that one. Maybe make the line at the bottom slightly less negative with something like "Byte count isn't everything". Even so, I'm afraid this might be encouraging new users to post answers that aren't golfed at all, because they don't like to golf but have an interesting/clever/creative/innovative solution. So yeah, I'm not really sure our intentions can be conveyed accurately in the space of a community ad without inadvertently sending the wrong message to some people.

Comment: @MartinEnder Yes, that was exactly my problem - how to convey a message in 1) a positive way, 2) a concise way and 3) not open to misinterpretation. How about "Byte count isn't everything - clever golfing is"? Or, "All languages are not equal - support clever golfing?"

Comment: One of those might work better, yeah.

Comment: I feel kind of odd seeing that answer linked in an ad. It's not a bad answer, and an ad for conscious voting isn't a bad idea. But imagine it being the third or fourth thing you read. Basically says: new user get frustrated here, people here vote poorly, and then blames the "new-ish users". <scarcasm> *BTW, welcome to PPCG!* </sarcasm>

Comment: @Linus I agree - but I'm not sure where this should link instead

Comment: As a suggestion, could link to the ["Why Vote?"](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) topic in the Help Center.

Comment: Two suggestions (perhaps subjective): (1) Make the upper text colour a little lighter, so the bottom text stands out more. (2) Vertically distribute the upper text more evenly. Currently there's too much blank space between the two texts, which doesn't look good

Comment: @LuisMendo Feel free to do so. I have made this a Community Wiki with the specific intent to have people with more experience in design improve on this ad. Font is Courier New.

Answer (score 27):

[image: Esoteric IDE — Interpreter/Debugger for esoteric programming languages]

Answer (score 21):

[Active bounties http://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/codegolf.stackexchange.com/bounty.png](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured)

Comment: This is an auto-updating ad [maintained by Kyle Cronin](http://apple.stackexchange.com/users/13/kyle-cronin) I believe. **Once they are bounties on main, this ad should update as a ticker to show it**. [See here for example](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/a/1521/44905)

Comment: Not as amazing as the others....

Comment: Are there any other things that it would be useful to auto-update in an ad? Could we have a few of these for different things?

Comment: @trichoplax yeah, the source for this is open and it woulnd't be too hard to setup a heroku server to serve the images. I cant think of anything that would be useful to show though

Comment: Oh I see - I was wondering how a png was able to show dynamic content - but it doesn't follow the "must be hosted on imgur" rule. I'm guessing this is acceptable if it's already being used on apple.SE?

Comment: There isn't anything that ties this to PPCG. Or anything specific to it.

Comment: @trichoplax I'm guessing. Many other sites such as CR use this ticker. I don't know if it's a new rule though. I'll check

Comment: @trichoplax IIRC there's a loophole where you post a dummy imgur link and then go back and edit it.

Comment: "Are currently 1" -> Unusable :P Not a serious problem, but could we report it somewhere? Generally I think incorrect grammar doesn't look very good.

Comment: I forgot what the text for no bounties is. If you know it, it might be a better idea for the alternate text.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I thought the fact that the goat has bad grammar was well established by now :|

Comment: @EʀɪᴋᴛʜᴇGᴏʟғᴇʀ But then they have to care to go and know how to get there. This is far from "useless".

Comment: Good idea for mouse over text: "See a question that's not getting any good answers? Place a bounty on it!".

Comment: FYI, [here](https://github.com/kylecronin/Stack-Exchange-Bounty-Ad) is the Github repo if you want something different.

Comment: Well, I saw the bounty-promotional content of this ad...

Comment: What happens if there are >99 bounties?

Comment: @mbomb007 Probably overflows. Do you see this being an issue, ever?

Comment: @Pavel Stack Overflow has 381 bounties currently. There are other sites on SE that use this ad.

Comment: @mbomb007, two things. 1. It's now 2017, so there's not much point editing this answer. 2. It's now 2017, so it's safe to assume that a lot of people view the site over https and get mixed content warnings/errors if images are included over http.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I was just seeing if that's the reason the image no longer shows. Not all sites support SSL. And I wasn't the first one to edit it.

Answer (score 21):

[image: Brainduck - Difficult languages need powerful IDEs]

Answer (score 11):

[image: Read Frequently Asked Questions. Get answers!]

Comment: "Visit" is better than "view" IMO. It still rhymes with "visit".

Comment: I see no benefit in either visiting or viewing the FAQ. I would prefer “read”.

Comment: I think this ad is quite aggressive as it stands now - it has a bit of a "Read the FAQ or don't bother coming here again"-feel to it. How about **"Are you new? Why not read the FAQ?"**

Comment: @sanchises Or maybe "Are you new? Check out the FAQ"? Honestly though, we do *really* want users to read it. It's saves us a lot of time editing and reviewing answers and questions.

Comment: Is the FAQ even up to date? I was under the impression that it wasn't

Comment: @muddyfish Click the link and see where it goes. It goes to meta questions tagged [meta-tag:faq], not to the FAQ.

Answer (score 8):

[image: Help this community grow -- follow us on twitter!]

Comment: What font does the text use?

Comment: We changed fonts when we made the new wider ads. The designer who did them, however, is out for the next week, so I can't actually get an answer until then.

Comment: @dorukayhan appears to be either Arial Bold or Helvetica Neue Bold

Comment: I need the font to create a new ad... (and no, it's not about avocados this time - this time it's serious) I assume the designer is in by now...

Comment: Is the designer in?

Comment: @GraceNote Update, please?