# Community Promotion Ads — 2019

Tags: discussion, community-ads

2019 is here! And with the new year, as usual, comes a new iteration of **Community Promotion Ads**! Let’s refresh these for the coming year :)

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- code puzzle blogs and websites
- interesting challenge sites
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/17302).

Answer (score 43):

[image: Over 600 online interpreters. Free of charge, open source, and ad-free.]

Comment: [Repost from 2018.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14689/12012)

Comment: What about compilers? How about *Over 600 online / programming languages / Open source. No charges or ads*?

Comment: @Adám gcc may be a compiler, but I think https://tio.run/#c-gcc is an interpreter.

Answer (score 35):

[image: Have a challenge idea? Iron out its bugs. Join us in the Sandbox!]

Comment: Repost of [this 2016 ad](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9466/41024). Image created by [Downgoat](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/40695/downgoat). The Sandbox is often missed by new users, this ad adds an ever-so-slight chance of somebody spotting it before posting their first question.

Comment: Maybe it should be "Sand out its bugs." Like with sandpaper smoothing out wood. It's not called the Laundry Room, and you don't iron bugs... you iron out wrinkles.

Comment: @mbomb007 LOL it's been like that for a few years and it has kinda become a staple, not sure I want to change it like that... :P

Comment: Sure it has, but it's never too late to poke fun.

Answer (score 20):

[image: Know how to vote!]

Comment: Repost of [this 2016 ad](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10138/41024). Image created by [Sanchises](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/32352/sanchises). This ad raises an extremely important point regarding the way we use our votes.

Answer (score 17):

[image: Bookmarklet — no install needed!]

Comment: [repost](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14693/43319)

Answer (score 15):

[image: Deadline-less (hence not searchable) bounties offered by users on various challenges]

Comment: Um... that thing in the middle... shouldn't it be blue? ;)

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Difficult question this is. It is blue in no-design sites, but green in the graduation script.

Comment: It's blue in all sites... the graduation script is another story. :P

Comment: Clearly we need an ad for the gradscript :D

Comment: @Pavel https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49530455#49530455

Answer (score 10):

[image: Bounties for everybody]

Comment: [repost](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14691/43319)

Answer (score 8):

[image: J and K are on topic too!]

Comment: [repost](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14708/43319)

Answer (score 5):

[image: Want to improve your Jelly skills? – Join Jelly HyperTraining!]

Comment: Repost of [this 2018 ad](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14696/41024). Image created by [Adám](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/43319/ad%c3%a1m).

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Comment: "enter image description here"?

Comment: Jelly Balls is an online editor for the Jelly language

Comment: @JellyBalls Offtopic to the question, but in the editor ball buttons' text renders white, nearly unreadable. Would you mind setting an explicit CSS rule to change it to black?

Answer (score -10):

[image: Help this community grow -- follow us on twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting