# Community Ads for 2021

Tags: discussion, community-ads

**September update:** Community Ads are now live network-wide. All ads with a score of 6 or higher, or with a score of 4 or higher *and* no downvotes will be displayed (except for any that have a note from the CM Team explaining why it wasn't selected). Go to [the main post on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364556/208518) for a list of the ads that are being displayed. And stay tuned for 2022's edition for the next opportunity to submit more ad proposals!

---

**AUGUST NOTE:** This post has now been locked and new submissions are not being accepted. Ad submissions are now undergoing review by the Community Team, and this question will be updated once the ads are live.

---

We're almost halfway through 2021, and [in case you missed it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364556/208518), Community Promotion Ads are gonna be a bit different this time! **TL;DR: submit and vote for ad proposals before August 2nd!**

#### What are Community Ads?

Community Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, or on other sites in the network. They can show up in the right sidebar, or in banners in question pages. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be considered by [the Community Management Team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99341/208518) to be displayed.

#### Why do we have Community Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. The goal of this initiative is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join. You may want to promote external resources, or Meta guidance for newcomers, for instance.

This initiative has an added goal of providing your community with *an opportunity to showcase exemplary questions from your main site, as well as frequently-linked-to guides from your Meta site*. While the latter makes sense to be shown solely on this site, the former can be shown all across the network. These should avoid hot button topics, and instead focus more on evergreen questions that show what your community’s all about.

#### Why do we reset the ads?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. Historically, we've reset the ads every year — since this is the first run of a new format, we'll run the ads collected in this post through the end of 2021 and reassess the rotation cycle then.

The community ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a previous exposure.

#### Are there restrictions to the ads I can post?

All proposed ads need to abide by [our Code of Conduct](/conduct). [Our ad creative guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/advertising/guidelines) also generally apply (note that the first 2 bullet points on the “Tracking” section do not apply, and a lot of the guidelines surrounding claims, comparisons, proof, etc., while still applicable, may not be particularly relevant). Finally, ads can not be promoting products nor soliciting programmer time or resources for: knowledge sharing or collaboration tools for technologists, or for sites where ad buyers are primarily targeting technologists.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored:

1. **Each answer must relate to a single ad submission.** Please do not post multiple ad submissions in the same answer.
2. All answers must be in one of the below formats:

   1. If you have an image for the ad you want to display on this site (must be the case for ads to external sources, which can't be shown on sites other than this one):

   ```
   [![Image name. Example: "community_ad_name_300x250"][1]][2]

     [1]: https://image-url
     [2]: https://clickthrough-url
   ```

   2. If you want to create an ad for a question from your main or meta site, to be advertised on this or other sites in the network (staff will generate a frame for the ad with this site's theme, for brand consistency):

   ```
   Question title  
   Question URL
   Ad size (right sidebar or banner ads)
   Site(s) to be displayed in. Can be:
     - "self" for ads to be displayed on this site
     - "all" for ads to be displayed all over the network
     - a specific subset of sites
   ```
3. Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels for right sidebar ads or 728 x 90 pixels for banner ads. Images can be double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF, PNG, or JPG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

#### Selection process

**This post will remain open for ad submissions and voting until August 2nd**. At that point, the question will be closed/locked, and no more ad submissions will be accepted. For ad submissions to be considered for selection by the Community Management Team, they must have **a minimum score of 6 at the time the post was closed/locked for submissions.** Given this is the first run with this new format, we may adjust the score threshold to be a bit lower if we see ads struggling to get to it (especially if the ads are not getting downvotes) by the time submissions and voting are closed.

#### Reporting statistics

Once this cycle is over, at the end of 2021, the Community Management Team will provide you with reporting statistics, as described in the "reporting" section of [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364556/208518).

---

Feel free to use the question's comment section to ask for any clarifications.

Comment: How strict are you on the "non-compete" clause on ads? For example [Try it online!](https://tio.run) contains advertising for the services that help it stay up (e.g. Dyalog APL), and it is incredibly widely used here, and has been one of the top Community adverts for the past ~5 years. By some reading of the non-compete clause, we wouldn't be allowed to advertise for that?

Comment: Will we be able to edit the ads after Aug 2nd?

Comment: "ads can not be promoting products nor soliciting programmer time or resources for: knowledge sharing or collaboration tools for technologists, or for sites where ad buyers are targeting technologists." means that we cannot have ads for other parts of Stack Exchange, right?

Comment: Feel free to include that for now — I know some cases are more of a gray area than others, and I'll make sure to keep y'all updated if something doesn't make the cut because of that clause :)

Comment: The ads will not be editable after August 2nd, @Adám, as I'd mentioned on MSE in response to your concerns. That may be addressed by quicker ad rotation in future iterations, as I mentioned it there. And as I mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364556/the-future-of-community-promotion-open-source-and-hot-network-questions-ads#comment1220652_364556), the clause doesn't apply to intra-network ads.

Comment: Banning "sites where ad buyers are primarily targeting technologists" seems to me like it defeats the entire purpose of these ads. They are run in order to target the users of this site, who *are primarily technologists*.

Comment: I've downvoted, because I'm disappointed about how this was rolled out. This *should* have been an easy win for y'all - the ability to advertise specific questions is a *very* good thing. However, y'all were given [feedback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364556/355458) on this idea a month ago, and you've all but ignored it, and the feedback you acted on has made it *very* vague (to the point where this has 2 close votes). I like Community Ads, they're probably one of the few systems of advertising I support. But I can't support the way you guys have done this

Comment: If we want to advertise a specific thing both in the side bar and in the banner, should we post two answers?

Comment: How do we [specify whether the ad should be displayed on the same site (mimicking the Community Promotion and Open Source Ads format), on all other sites (mimicking the Hot Network Questions Ads format), or on a subset of other sites (say, on all the tech sites)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364556/317948)?

Comment: I tried to address all of the feedback that could be addressed in the scope of this trial, @cairdcoinheringaahing, and I'll keep the rest in mind for any post-trial runs of Community Ads (and hopefully try to address as much as possible from the yet-to-be-addressed feedback then). What exactly do you feel is vague in this post, and how can I help clarify it?

Comment: The post says "Each answer must relate to a single ad submission," @Adám, so an individual submission for a sidebar and banner ad would be required. And the 2nd template guidance above should clear your question about where the ad should be displayed, no?

Comment: @JNat You'd probably be better asking Adám what's vague - I haven't VTC'ed but I know he has and he'd be able to explain better than I could.

Comment: @JNat Aha, so picture ads to external resources cannot be pushed to other sites? That's not at all clear from your post.

Comment: Could I say it any clearer than "If you have an image for the ad you want to display on this site (must be the case for ads to external sources)" @Adám? I thought that was pretty clear :)

Comment: @JNat Yes, I think that could be clearer if it said explicitly that "ads to external resources cannot be shown on other sites".

Comment: Clarified that in the post, @Adám — other sites haven't mentioned that as unclear, but happy to make it clear_er_ :)

Answer (score 27):

[image: Tio: Try it online]

Comment: [Repost](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18639/96037)

Answer (score 18):

[image: Have a challenge idea? Iron out its bugs. Join us in the Sandbox!]

Comment: [Repost](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18640)

Answer (score 18):

> **NOTE FROM CM TEAM:** As per the guidance in the original post, this ad submission will not be selected to be displayed on site. To be more specific, this is an ad promoting a knowledge sharing or collaboration platform, aimed at technologists.

---

[image: Code Golf on codidact.com]

Answer (score 13):

[image: Bookmarklet: Language bars, key-bindings, and character compositions with no install needed!]

Comment: [Repost](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18643)

Answer (score 12):

[image: Know how to vote!]

Comment: [Repost](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18641)

Comment: If you want to keep this image, this ad is fine as is. You main want to have it in a frame that reflects the site's theme, though, in which case the second format for submission would be more appropriate — it'd look something like [this](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/E2uw4WyXIAIFwm1.png), but with this site's theme instead — up to you :)

Answer (score 11):

[image: Esolangs.org: esoteric programming languages wiki]

Comment: [Repost](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/19106)

Answer (score 10):

[image: The APL Orchard chat room. Other array languages are on topic too!]

Comment: [Repost](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18644)

Answer (score 10):

[image: APL problem solving competition: referral prizes available!]

Answer (score 10):

Title: Welcome to the site - check out our information page first!

URL: [Welcome to Code Golf and Coding Challenges Stack Exchange!](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833)

Size: Banner

Displayed on: self

Answer (score 9):

[image: Deadline-less (hence not searchable) bounties offered by users on various challenges]

Comment: [Repost](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18638)

Answer (score 9):

[image: Bounties for everybody]

Comment: [Repost](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18642)

Answer (score 9):

[image: Esoteric IDE: interpreter for esoteric programming languages]

Comment: [Repost](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/19108)

Answer (score 9):

[image: Want to improve your Jelly skills? Join the Jelly HyperTraining chat room!]

Comment: [Repost](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18645)

Answer (score 9):

[image: APL problem solving competition: referral prizes available!]

Answer (score 9):

Title: Try your hand at code golf and other coding challenges!

URL: [Welcome to Code Golf and Coding Challenges Stack Exchange!](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833)

Size: Right sidebar

Displayed on: all except self

Comment: Is it worth changing this to be a network wide ad?

Comment: advertise it only to self and CR /s

Comment: I think the title should skip "Welcome to" and "Stack Exchange"

Comment: @Adám Modified it slightly

Comment: Actually, shouldn't the title be different depending on the target. I like the new formulation for all other sites, but somehting like "Welcome to the site – read this first" might be better for self-ads.

Answer (score 9):

Title: Short code isn't everything. Find out how to vote!

URL: [How can we help users who are put off by the use of golfing languages?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10127/how-can-we-help-users-who-are-put-off-by-the-use-of-golfing-languages/10132#10132)

Size: banner

Displayed on: self

Answer (score 9):

Title: Welcome to the site - check out our information page first!

URL: [Welcome to Code Golf and Coding Challenges Stack Exchange!](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833)

Size: Right sidebar

Displayed on: self

Answer (score 9):

[image: Dyalog APL seeds: overview of APL, intro to resources, demo of real-world apps]

Answer (score 9):

[image: Join the Vyxal community and start winning code golf challenges!]

Comment: Is it just me or does this look like it has been auto-sharpened? The contrast is really low too.

Comment: @Adám It's been forced to a lower resolution. I am not sure what's with the artifacts around the edges; those were there in the original and I actually scaled it down. I agree with the contrast issue though - I'll see if I can touch this up a bit.

Comment: Advertising a single language doesn't really seem like a good idea to me. Vyxal's the only one with an advertisement, so it might give some people the impression that it's "the official CGCC language" or something.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms even though they aren't the same type of ad, APL and Jelly also have language-specific-related ads, and I think it's quite obvious for anyone who spends more than 30 seconds on this site that people use a wide arrangement of languages by clicking on literally any challenge with more than zero answers and scrolling half a page.

Comment: @downvoters why the downvotes?

Answer (score 8):

[image: Dyalog APL seeds: overview of APL, intro to resources, demo of real-world apps]