# Why is the site logo a medal?

Tags: discussion, site-design

What does a medal have to do with codes and computers? Is it a reference to the site badges and privileges? Or maybe a reference to the Olympiad awards? Also, why is it between two accolades?

Comment: Why _not_ a medallion? Medallions are nice.

Comment: The site name is Code Golf and Coding **Challenges**, so I always assumed it was as if the winners of those challenges get medals.

Comment: If you posted this question on main, think about what kind of objective criterion it would be found to lack :)

Comment: It's not just a medal - it's enclosed in `{ }` which represents the __code__ aspect of the competition.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Because we're a site about competition

See [Adám's answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17551/66833) to the question [asking for input on the site design](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/17548/66833), and the [original proposed logo](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7978/66833) which was incorporated into the old [Graduation Userscript](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7955/66833).

In short, we host challenges, where people compete. A medal seems very representative of that, which is why its used in our logo and our badges, the two big custom design elements each site gets.