# Cannot close a question even though >500 reputation

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

[image]

As you can see in the image, I cannot close the question even though I have >500 reputation.

I cannot blame it on caching because I passed 500 reputation a long time ago (greater than a month).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a bug. The privilege levels changed with the new design, so you now need 3000 reputation to close questions.

From *[Congratulations! Your site design is now live!](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17760/congratulations-your-site-design-is-now-live)*

> If you're noticing your [privileges](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) have changed, they've been updated to the higher levels.

Comment: Additional hint: [Can we raise the privilege levels?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16151/can-we-raise-the-privilege-levels) has now [meta-tag:status-completed] tag.