# Why are people being so hateful with the down votes?

Tags: discussion

The three newest questions are all in negative territory.  I am new here and it does not seem very friendly.  In a high traffic site I can see the luxury of being negative occasionally but please be more encouraging.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure what you mean by "hateful", so I'm going to assume that you mean

> Why are people downvoting questions?

The short answer is because they think they're [bad questions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). In fact, I've just voted to close one of them, and another one is already closed.

Writing a good question [takes effort](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/122/194), and should be encouraged with upvotes. But precisely because of that, a good question can easily be swamped in bad questions, and this will never be a high-traffic site if all of the questions are poorly specified or off-topic. **We don't want to encourage bad questions**. In fact, discouraging them is a *good* thing. The site is better off having a few good questions than a lot of crap.