# Count question score toward tag badges

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, challenges, badges

Related: [Increase reputation awarded for questions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7683/increase-reputation-awarded-for-questions)

It has recently came to my attention that tag badges are only awarded based on answer votes. For a site like Stack Overflow, that makes sense, as providing good answers is the perfect way to demonstrate that you know what you're talking about in a certain field. However, for this site, writing a good challenge can take a lot of work.

Can we get question votes to count along with answer votes toward tag badges? I'm not sure if this is as easily changeable as the amount of reputation awarded for question upvotes but it makes sense for this site.

Comment: I had a brief chat with a dev and apparently this can't be set on a per-site basis; the change would have to apply network-wide. He did recommend leaving this up and seeing what kind of support it gets though.

Comment: ruSO: [Do we need tag bages for questions?](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/2330/178988) (in Russian).

Comment: @Qwertiy If this is something people would like to see implemented network-wide, it should be posted on Meta.SE rather than on individual site metas. I don't want to speak on behalf of anyone, but the impression I got from the dev was that it's rather unlikely it would be done. When I mentioned it in my previous comment, it was more to serve as a "don't get your hopes up" kind of thing. :P

Comment: @AlexA., I just thought that it is a good idea anyway as good questions are valuable for any site. So I desided to ask what other community thinks about that. For now rating is +3 -0 with comment that we need some way to distinguish questions badge and answers badge. It's just for a discussion, not for implementation. It would be better to have it already discussed before posting on metaSE.

Comment: I originally upvoted this, but now I think this would be a somewhat lukewarm solution and would rather see [separate badges that only count challenges](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8598/8478).

Comment: I am marking this as [meta-tag:status-deferred] because we have other things we need to prioritize right now. However, there is a possibility that CMs will be able to create and award custom tags in the future, and we will look into providing that to prominent challenge setters.