# Is the increased rep for challenge upvotes going to happen?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, challenges, reputation

I have read on here that many several times it has be suggested that challenge upvotes count for more rep. Is that happening?

[Increase reputation awarded for questions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7683/increase-reputation-awarded-for-questions) Is one place it was mentioned but I have yet to see anything else